# Can ALAssetLibrary load image file in the Document folder?

Tags: ios, metadata, alassetslibrary

ALAssetLibrary can get image file info from the camera roll or album very easy. However, when I try to use it to load the image file in the Document folder(sandbox), it always gets nothing. This is my code:

```
//Get full file path in the Document folder.(Yes, IMG001.jpg exists in that place)
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* theFileName = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMG001.jpg"];
NSURL* theFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theFileName];

//Now try to load the asset.
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:theFileURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    //asset here is always nil.
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    //it does not run in this place.
}];
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url passed to **assetForURL** function should be of an asset URL previously retrieved from an **ALAsset** object. And an **ALAsset** object represents a photo or a video managed by the **Photo application**. So you cannot use ALAssetLibrary in this case.

To get an image from document directory use the following :

```
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* imageFilePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMG001.jpg"];
    UIImage* imageRequired = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imageFilePath];
```

Comment: Thanks. But the UIImage does not contains the metadata. Indeed, my purpose is to save my pictures to the camera roll with the metadata. This can be done by the method of ALAssetLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:. So, my target is the metadata. I wanted to get the metadata via ALAssetLibrary.